# What does "position" mean in iconv error message?

Tags: text-processing, emacs, editors, character-encoding

I get error when converting a large file:

```
$ iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 2001.txt -o 2001_u.txt
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 245256667
```

What does the position mean in this error? I tried it is not line number. 
How to get to the position in other tools or editors like emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the 245256667 byte of the file. If you do a:

```
dd if=2001.txt of=error.txt bs=1 count=10 skip=245256667
```

You should be able to see the non valid utf8 sequence by doing a `hexdump -C error.txt`

Answer (score 2):

With `vim` you can just

```
:go POSITION+1
```

e.g.

```
:go 245256668
```

or alternatively, in command mode :

```
POSITION+1go
```

that is

```
245256668go
```