# Why did this file not convert to UTF-8 when using iconv?

Tags: linux, character-encoding

`Versions:` **Linux 2.6; Bash 4.1.2; iconv 2.12**

The ISO conversion returned no errors, yet the converted file still shows as **US-ASCII**.

**Question**
How can I transcode `foobar.txt` to UTF-8?

```
$> file -bi foobar.txt
   text/plain; charset=us-ascii

$> iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 foobar.txt >  foobar_utf8.txt
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 573167

$>iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 foobar.txt >  foobar_utf8.txt
$>
$> file foobar_utf8.txt
   foobar_utf8.txt: ASCII text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is always proper UTF-8, so no conversion was needed — if it *was* ASCII.

The `file` utility does not look at the entire file, but only at the beginning.  If it is large enough, then `file` can overlook a non-ASCII byte.  `573167` is probably past any "beginning" that `file` might consider.

On the other hand, you can only use `iconv` to convert a *known* character set to UTF-8.  You could try a few likely choices, check for success — and compare the resulting files.

If the file is one of the ISO-8859-x flavors for instance, you would have to gauge success by inspecting the resulting file.  Since `iconv` only complained about the file after  573167 bytes, you might consider using `cut` to extract a portion of the file beginning at that character-offset, and letting `file` try to identify it.

Comment: So why would it error when I converted from US-ASCII to UTF-8 if the coding is legit?

Comment: For help in locating position: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152792/what-does-position-mean-in-iconv-error-message

Comment: yes, `dd` would work well.  I suggested `cut` because it is simpler.